# Spring MVC maven build: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, netbeans

I'm using net beans and receive error below when trying to build the project:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project TessWeb: Compilation failure
>   com/kevin/app/TessController.java:[30,55] cannot find symbol
>   symbol:   method value()
>   location: @interface org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody

I have following pom.xml:

```
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <springframework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <jackson.version>2.7.5</jackson.version>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have tried many ways to resolve the problem but none of them works. Please help.

Comment: Delet `<type>` tag from pom.xml file and also post the sample code where its saying the exception `com/kevin/app/TessController.java:[30,55] cannot find symbol...`.

Comment: Your pom.xml has `spring-webmvc`. So you don't need to add `spring-web`. As @SachinSarawgi said, it may be `type` tag problem. Delete that dependency anyway.

Comment: @Zhuoshi did you tried the solution?

Comment: Pls show your complete stack trace and some code where you are getting this error. And also <properties> start tag is missing here.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi removing <type> does not work. There seems to be something wrong with my netbeans. Using Eclipse I'm able to build the project. exception came from `public  @ResponseBody String resolve(@RequestBody("input") String input) {`

Comment: So did you able to resolve the error or its still their. If present then post the code where its showing the error.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi I have resolved the problem, but I'm also interested in why the exception is thrown. As I said, exception came from @RequestBody in 
`@RestController @RequestMapping("/service") public class TessController { @RequestMapping(value="/resolve", method=RequestMethod.POST) public String resolve(@RequestBody("input") String input) {`